# Create Dataframe with variable number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have created this function in orden to create a dataframe that adds a new completed row everytime the functions is called by an agent. The thing is, I want the previous rows created to stay in the dataframe, that is why I used the instruction append. It keeps creating the dataframe from scratch everytime it is called so the previous row is erased, I want the index to keep increasing and adding new rows.

Here is the code of the function in Python:

```
def list_active_agents(agent_id, agent_name, agent_type, activation_time):
    list = []
    list.append({
        'agent_id': agent_id,
        'agent_name': agent_name,
        'agent_type': agent_type,
        'activation_time': activation_time
    })
    columns = ['agent_id', 'agent_name', 'agent_type', 'activation_time']
    list_aa = pd.DataFrame(list, columns=columns)    
    list_aa = list_aa.drop_duplicates(keep='first')     
    return list_aa
```

I have tryed using the instruction;
`list_aa.empty`, to acknowledge when the DataFrame is empty but it doesn't work the way I want to.

Help.

Answer (score 0):

**try:**

```
li = lambda x,y,z,w :  {
        'agent_id': x,
        'agent_name': y,
        'agent_type': z,
        'activation_time': w
    }
columns = ['agent_id', 'agent_name', 'agent_type', 'activation_time']
list_aa = pd.DataFrame([], columns=columns)
def list_active_agents(agent_id, agent_name, agent_type, activation_time):
    global list_aa
    list_aa = list_aa.append(li(agent_id, agent_name, agent_type, activation_time), ignore_index=True)
    list_aa = list_aa.drop_duplicates(keep='first')     
    return list_aa
```

---

```
list_active_agents(1, 'a', 't', 10)
list_active_agents(1, 'b', 't', 10)
```

---

```
    agent_id    agent_name  agent_type  activation_time
0   1           a           t           10
1   1           b           t           10
```

---

```
list_active_agents(1, 'a', 't', 10)
list_active_agents(1, 'a', 't', 10)
```

---

```
    agent_id    agent_name  agent_type  activation_time
0   1           a           t           10
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not good practice to use the keyword `list` as a variable, it is already defined in python. I will use `my_list` instead in the following code. The other problem that I see is that you redefined an empty list every time the function is called, so you lose the previous rows. I would use the previous dataframe as an input to the function and append to it. The first time you run the function you can run it without the argument `dataframe` and the function will create it itself. You can also add some safety lines in the beginning of the function, where you test whether the value passed to dataframe is None or a pandas dataframe, to make sure no list or dict etc. is passed by mistake.

Note that when you pass a list of dicts to DataFrame, you don't need to explicitly specify the columns names, pandas automatically uses the keys of the dictionaries.

If you don't want to add the dataframe as an argument to the function, another possibility would be to define it as a global.

```
import pandas as pd

def list_active_agents(agent_id, agent_name, agent_type, activation_time, dataframe=None):
    my_list = [{
        'agent_id': agent_id,
        'agent_name': agent_name,
        'agent_type': agent_type,
        'activation_time': activation_time
    }]
    if dataframe == None:
        dataframe_result = pd.DataFrame(my_list)
    else:
        dataframe_result = dataframe.append(my_list, ignore_index=True)
    dataframe_result = dataframe_result.drop_duplicates(keep='first')     
return dataframe_result
```